# Orthogonal projection to prove eigenvalue interlacing when it is known true for the inverses.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, inverse, projection-matrices

I have the matrix
$$
M=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2&a\vec{v}^T\\
a\vec{v}&B+\vec{v}\vec{v}^T
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Since
$$
M^{-1}=\frac{1}{a^2}
\begin{pmatrix}
1+\vec{v}^TB^{-1}\vec{v}&-a\vec{v}^TB^{-1}\\
-aB^{-1}\vec{v}&a^2B^{-1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
using the orthogonal projection
$$
P=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\vec{0}^T\\
\vec{0}&I
\end{pmatrix},
$$
with $I$ the $n\times n$ identity matrix, it is easy to show that $M^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ have their eigenvalues interlaced, i.e., $m_1^{-1}\geq b_1^{-1}\geq m_2^{-1}\geq b_2^{-1}\geq\cdots m_{n}^{-1}\geq b_{n}^{-1}\geq m_{n+1}^{-1}$, where $m_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $M$, and $b_i$ that of $B$. Therefore, $m_1\leq b_1\leq m_2\leq b_2\leq\cdots m_{n}\leq b_{n}\leq m_{n+1}$, and it can be stated that the eigenvalues of $M$ and $B$ are also interlaced.

Is it possible to arrive at the same conclusion without resorting to inverting matrices? In other words, what orthogonal projection acting upon $M$ will produce $B$?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach to showing that the eigenvalues interlace. Instead of using Cauchy's interlacing theorem, use [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_about_perturbation). Note that we can write $M = B_0 + R$, where $B_0$ and $R$ are given by
$$
B_0 = \pmatrix{0\\&B}, \quad R = \pmatrix{a^2 & av^T\\av & vv^T} = \pmatrix{a\\ v} \pmatrix{a\\v}^T.
$$
If $m_1\leq \cdots \leq m_{n+1}$ are the eigenvalues of $M$ and $\beta_1 \leq \cdots \leq \beta_{n+1}$ are the eigenvalues of $B_0$, then because $R$ has one positive eigenvalue and $n$ zero eigenvalues, we have $\beta_i \leq m_i \leq \beta_{i+1}$.

On the other hand, the eigenvalues of $B_0$ are simply the eigenvalues of $B$ with an extra $0$ eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very interesting approach indeed. However, isn't the result for this case contingent on the eigenvalues being always positive for $M$ and $B$?

Comment: @GeoArt Yes, but the same can be said for your inverse argument: $a^{-1} \leq b^{-1} \implies a \geq b$ only applies if $a,b$ have the same sign